# public ssh id is different on id_rsa.pub than in ansible_ssh_host_key_rsa_public

Tags: linux, ssh, python, ansible, ansible-playbook

I would like to do a passwordless SSH login to another Linux server,
and I would like to do the setup using ansible

Could you please advise why

1. `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
2. `hostvars[item]['ansible_ssh_host_key_rsa_public']`

are different ?

Here is the task used as an example:

```
- debug: msg="ssh-rsa {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_ssh_host_key_rsa_public'] }} {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_user_id'] }}@{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_hostname'] }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups.pmacct }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups.ipacc

- meta: end_play
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ansible_ssh_host_key_rsa_public` is a host key from `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` file on remote host.

`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is a public key of your local user account.